# How to create a extra setting option under product setting option in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Create the section beneath the products tab
 **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'wcslider_add_section' );
function wcslider_add_section( $sections )
{   
    $sections['wcslider'] = __( 'WC Slider', 'text-domain' );
    return $sections;
}
```

Where To add This code (I mean in which file) ?

Comment: I have tried this Official Tutorial , but they haven't explained where to add this code, In which file and how to call it ?

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the `functions.php` file in your wordpress theme.

Comment: I want to add this into core structure of WordPress Not Into any theme. So it will be independent of any theme.